# how to import a .3ds model in Blender 2.65 via console

Tags: python, import

I just need to import a .3ds model into the scene using the console/scripting.

The main file is in C:Users\Me\Desktop\Maps and the .3ds model is in C:Users\Me\Desktop\Maps\Models

I'm pretty sure I should be using bpy.ops.import_scene.autodesk_3ds() but I honestly just keep getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.65\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py",
    line 185, in __call__     C_dict, C_exec, C_undo = BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.65\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py",
    line 142, in _parse_args
  raise ValueError("1-3 args execution context is supported") ValueError: 1-3 args execution context is supported
```

Exactly how should I type out that line?

Comment: do you tried all parameters from API???  http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/bpy.ops.import_scene.html?highlight=autodesk_3ds#bpy.ops.import_scene.autodesk_3ds

Comment: I'm using 2.65  http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_65_9/bpy.ops.import_scene.html  

but i have tried all parametres, still not working

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.65\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 185, in __call__
    C_dict, C_exec, C_undo = BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.65\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 142, in _parse_args
    raise ValueError("1-3 args execution context is supported")
ValueError: 1-3 args execution context is supported`

Answer (score 3):

This line of code worked for me:

```
 bpy.ops.import_scene.autodesk_3ds(filepath = 'C:/path/to/your/file.3ds')
```

The tricky place is that you have to prepend 'filepath = ' before the actual path. You will be getting an error otherwise.